# How can I integrate OpenFeint in an Android application?

Tags: android, iphone, openfeint

I would like to integrate OpenFeint in an Android application, because I have an existing iPhone game that I would like to interact with.

However, when I try to add OpenFeint in my Android project, the sample OpenFeint project is not running in Eclipse.  I get an error that says that the "OpenFeintSampleApi" is not found.  What could be causing this?  Does anyone have better instructions for using OpenFeint?

Answer (score 1):

This article was helpful for me: [Getting Started with OF Android 1.10.2:
4. Integrate OpenFeint Into Your Game](http://support.openfeint.com/dev/getting-started-with-of-android-1-10-24-integrate-openfeint-into-your-game/)

A few things to be aware of that the article doesn't mention; make sure the OpenFeint project you import has a compiler compliance level of 1.6 (Project > Properties > Java Compiler) or you'll get errors about the @Override annotations.

Another thing it doesn't mention is referencing the OpenFeint project as a library project. Right click your project > Properties > Android > Library > Add... and select the OpenFeint project.